# backticks are getting converted to &#x60; when I save in VSCode

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This strange thing is happening in only this particular line. I have no idea why. It can't be a Prettier or Vetur issue otherwise all of my backticks should covert on save. It's only these ones in this line of code. So my only solution is to not use string literals. How can I switch that ES6 syntax to ES5? The part in the v-slot

```
 <template v-for="slot in slots" v-slot:[`cell(${slot.field})`]="data">
     <slot :name="slot.name" :tbl="data"></slot>
 </template>
```

For the sake of clarity, this is what I get when I save

```
 <template v-for="slot in slots" v-slot:[&#x60;cell(${slot.field})&#x60;]="data">
    <slot :name="slot.name" :tbl="data"></slot>
 </template>
```

Comment: I don't think it's valid to use the computed property name syntax in the attributes of a vue template. They're automatically getting html-encoded.

Comment: ES5 syntax would be `v-slot:['cell('+slot.field+')']="data"` but I don't think that would matter.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi that helped